# ip route del does not delete entire table

Tags: linux, routes

I have recently started using `ip route` commands for advanced routing stuff. Now I have come across something rather puzzling to me. A default route added to a table will be easily deleted whereas another route remains.

I add these two rules:

```
ip route add dev wlan0 default via 192.168.0.1 table 21
ip route add dev wlan0 192.168.0.0/24 table 21
```

Now if I do:

```
ip route show table 21
```

I see both of these rules present.

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  scope link
```

If I then try to delete table 21, and show it again:

```
ip route del table 21
ip route show table 21
```

There is still that rule remaining.

```
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  scope link
```

Can anyone explain this? The man page says that del is designed to delete a ROUTE, which also includes tables.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As @user3291010 has already pointed out, to delete a full table, use the following command:

This command deletes table 21:

```
ip route flush table 21
```

The command you tried is used to remove specific rules from a table. It wants a prefix to match on. When you didn't supply the prefix, it just deleted the first entry, which happened to be the default route.

To remove the second entry, and only the second entry, you could run this command:

```
ip route delete table 21 192.168.0.0/24
```

As far as I know, there is no way to delete all entries using the `delete` command.

Comment: Syntax to delete individual entries is not clear either. The syntax `ip route delete 192.168.1.3/24` only deleted some of the entries before starting to output `RTNETLINK answers: No such process` which presumably means everything is clear, however executing `ip r show table local` still shows more like these `broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev ens160 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.3` and `local 192.168.1.3 dev ens160 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.1.3`. Dozens of experiments reveal no working syntax to remove these. `man ip-route` doesn't help either.

Comment: Okay, found working syntax with an AI: it is a `ip route delete broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev ens160 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.3` *(probably may be shortened)* and `ip r delete table local local 192.168.1.3 dev ens160` accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe try:

```
ip route flush table 21
```

Comment: That definitely works, I know that. I was just curious as to why this single rule should remain in there after issuing a delete command.

Comment: If I am not mistaken (the man page is a little opaque), ip route del ROUTE deletes a route. If ROUTE matches more than one route, I believe it deletes the first matching route. It doesn't delete all matching routes, or a table.